# Function that returns the sum of the first n places of an array

Tags: java, function, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that returns the sum of the first n places in an array. This is my code (Java):

```
static int sumN(int[] A, int n)
  {
    if (n == 0) return n;
    return sumN(A, (n-1)) + A[n];
  }
```

This doesn't work as intended. Do you have any ideas? I also lack a sufficient if-n-is-weird-return-something-else.

Comment: *How* doesn't it work?

Comment: It doesn't work because, for example if A = {1, 2, 10, -7, 8, 99} then the function returns 11 if I type sumN(A, 3). It returns 14 if I type sumN(A, 4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int sumN(int[] A, int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    return A[n-1] + sumN(A, n-1);
}
```

There were a couple of problems with indexes, remember that arrays in Java are 0-based. You can verify it works as expected:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 10, -7, 8, 99};
System.out.println(sumN(a, 4));
=> 6
```

Comment: @devnull yep, fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that still doesn't work. The function returns 209 when I type sumN(A, 4) where A = {1, 2, 10, -7, 8, 99}.

Comment: I tried the code I see now, it doesn't work. The only thing different is that he returns 0 and uses A[n-1], right?

Comment: @user1614466 what do you mean, "it doesn't work"? it returns the correct result for your example

Comment: It should return 6, not 209. Or am I misunderstanding something? It takes the first 4 numbers and sums them together.

Comment: @user1614466 er, it _is_ returning `6`.

Comment: @user1614466 Are you sure all your array items are integers? And code is nicer to put at http://pastebin.com

Comment: @user1614466 that's not my code. Why don't you just copy what I wrote above? it's correct, it's working...

Comment: I apologize for my stupidity, I forgot that I also have a function that switches the numbers in A from left to right. I'm really sorry.

Comment: @user1614466 oh, don't worry, there's nothing to apologise, it was an honest mistake :) . And please, don't forget to accept this answer, if it was helpful for you!

Comment: Well his answer prompted me to test the indexes of the array. But seeing as he likely copied yours, I'll mark yours as correct (also to make up for your lost time because of my mistake). Thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return `n` but `A[0]` there. Also I added a check for n out of range.

```
static int sumN(int[] A, int n) {
    if (n < 0 || n > A.length - 1) return 0; // or some error value
    if (n == 0) return A[0]; // so not n
    return sumN(A, (n-1)) + A[n];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. The function returns 112 when I type sumN(A, 4) where A = {1, 2, 10, -7, 8, 99}.

Answer (score 0):

Why using recursive method when you can use direct way to summering the numbers :)

Comment: I know this is a really bad way because this can be easily solved in a simpler way, but the instructions said so.

Comment: i see , so use the solution above given by @Oscar Lopez

Answer (score 0):

look to this solution directly from netbeans IDE :)
[image]

it working very well :)